# How to filter numbers that contain unique digits?

Tags: python, algorithm

You have a list of numbers and you want to filter out those numbers that contain unique digits, i.e. each digit may only occur once in the number.

Positive examples:

- 985
- 58293.6
- 0.1246

Negative examples:

- 9585 (5 occurs twice)
- 58293.666 (6 occurs three times)
- 0.12461 (1 occurs twice)

How would you do that? My own idea is to convert each number to a string and then check whether the size of the set made out of the string's characters is equal to the length of the string. Something like that:

```
def uniques(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        str_number = str(number)
        if len(set(str_number)) == len(str_number):
            yield number

for i in uniques(xrange(1000, 1050)):
    print i

1023
1024
1025
1026
1027
1028
1029
1032
1034
1035
1036
1037
1038
1039
1042
1043
1045
1046
1047
1048
1049
```

Is there a way to do it without converting the integers to strings first?

Comment: Don't convert it back. Take an other variable for the stringified version of the number.

Comment: Especially if your input contains `float`s...

Comment: Aside from that, I think your approach is straightforward and easy to understand. I would go with it.

Comment: @Matthias Good point, this gives a bit more performance to the algorithm.

Comment: _Numbers_ as such don't have any "digits". It's only a string representation of a number that can contain or lack specific characters. So, you cannot count "digits" without converting ints to strings first (using python built-ins or explicitly). As to floats, the problem is only solvable up to a chosen precision, because there's no way to express arbitrary floats unambiguously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it without converting the integers to strings
>   first and then convert them back?

Yes, you could use `divmod` to find the digits base 10, but this is not faster than the method you posted:

```
def uniques2(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        seen = set()
        quotient = number
        while quotient > 10:
            quotient, remainder = divmod(quotient, 10)
            if remainder in seen:
                break
            else:
                seen.add(remainder)
        else:
            yield number
```

Comment: +1. Very nice. That's exactly what I was looking for. On my machine, your method is even slightly faster than my solution. Well done. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
def predicate(n):
    s = repr(n)
    return len(s) == len(set(s))
filtered_numbers = [ n for n in numbers if predicate(n) ]
```

or, if you prefer filter function:

```
filtered_numbers = filter(predicate, numbers)
```

or:

```
filtered_numbers = filter(lambda n: len(repr(n)) == len(set(repr(n))), numbers)
```

Comment: So using `repr` instead of `str`, that is the same thing saying in different way

Comment: @Abhijit, there is a little difference between repr(1.0/7.0) and str(1.0/7.0), for example.

Comment: @IvanYurchenko: I understand that difference, but in this case, technically its the same

Comment: `timeit.timeit('repr(1.0)') => 0.1439499855041504`, `timeit.timeit('str(1.0)') => 0.23338007926940918` on my machine. `repr` is superior in this case.

Comment: @frb On my system `str()` is 3 times faster than `repr()`.

Comment: +1 for using `repr`. It's considerably faster on my machine than `str`. Besides that, your solution is basically the same as mine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a regex-based solution, consider the following regex :

```
(?![\d.]*([\d.])[\d.]*\1)^[\d.]+$
```

That is, match a sequence of digits and periods if there are no duplicate digits and there is not a duplicate decimal point.

Update (thanks @frb): the correct way to write this in Python is

```
re.match(r"(?![\d.]*([\d.])[\d.]*\1)^[\d.]+$",str_number).group(0)
```

Comment: @frb IIUC, the source is a number _converted_ to string, so `1.1.1` cannot occur. Anyways, `1.1.1` should _not_ match. If you want to complain, complain about `1.2.3`

Comment: @frb `1.1.1` doesn't match: link: http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%3F!%5B%5Cd.%5D*(%5Cd)%5B%5Cd.%5D*%5C1)%5E%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%24&input=1.1.1 ) and I can't see why Python should be different nor I can try it out

Comment: @frb perhaps it needs some escaping or `$1` instead of `\1` for backreferences? I'm a regex-fan, not python-guru.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22702/discussion-between-frb-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: conclusion: use raw literals or escape properly

Comment: @frb people seem to think your comment still applies. Do you think you could remove it (or upvote mine, so it's visible), please?

Comment: Done. Sorry about that, I'm pretty new to SO (just not to Python ;) ).

Comment: @JanDvorak Your regex doesn't work. For each number I try, I get an empty string `''` back as result. Can you please check it again?

Comment: @PeterStahl how are you using the regex? I am no python guru but the regex is definitely correct, and `frb` has been successful in using it using the syntax I've pasted here

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm sorry, it was my fault. Using `re.match()` I get correct matches but not if I use `re.findall()` which I've tried before. With the latter, I always get an empty string as the result. I don't know why at the moment. Anyway, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Using collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def unique(seq):
    return any(x > 1 for x in Counter(seq).values())
```

This will work for any sequence, not only strings.

And only now I noticed that you didn't want to convert to strings... not sure why, but I'll let the answer stay.

Comment: -1. This is not what I was asking for. Please read my question again.